# how to develop win8 apps (html5 and js) with speech recognition

Tags: html, windows-8, speech-recognition, winjs, speech-to-text

I develop a windows 8 application (html and js) and I try to add a voice control system (microsoft speech) the first question is:
is it possible to add a dll (microsoft.speech)  to my project and did you know a good web site describe this 
thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **bing speech recognition control** for this.This has been released recently. You need to install it from visual studio gallery.For more details on installation and usage of bing speech recognition control please refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn434583.aspx

Comment: Thank you very match, did you know how many languages ​​are available ?

Comment: English (United States and United Kingdom), French, German, Japanese, Mandarin (Chinese Simplified and Chinese Traditional), and Spanish.

Comment: Also note that it's not free to use beyond the currently specified limits.